# What does "roll your eyes" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across the following sentence in a technical documentation that explains about integration with HTTP protocol.  What does "rolled your eyes" mean here?

Excerpt:

> If you’re a developer you’re likely
>   fairly familiar with this protocol —
>   you may have even ***rolled your eyes*** at
>   the sight of it — but it’s worth
>   mentioning to emphasize our
>   integration’s dependency on proper,
>   well-formed HTTP requests.

Comment: An example emote in animated gif form:
http://whitefyre.com/rolleyes.gif

Comment: It would also be interesting to know whether this phrase is of American origin.

Comment: And also the gesture, for that matter.

Comment: Well i rolled my eyes at a teacher and i got in trouble becuse of nothing its dump to get in trouble for that!!!

Comment: @horatio - My antivirus (McAfee) gives me a big red warning about following that link. Do you have one that is less risky? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You (quite literally) roll your eyes when you don't believe something or don't care about it. In this particular case, it is implied that you might be so familiar with the protocol that it's all old news to you. It's all over the place, nothing special, so seeing it *yet again* makes you roll your eyes.

Comment: Well, not very literally. "I was working on a case.  It had to be a case, because I couldn't afford a desk.  Then I saw her.  This tall blond lady.  She must have been tall because I was on the third floor.  She rolled her deep blue eyes towards me.  I picked them up and rolled them back.  We kissed.  She screamed.  I took the cigarette from my mouth and kissed her again." etc.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: "Roll eyes toward..." and such have significantly different meaning from "Rolling eyes"(,period.) just as "throwing something up" has a different meaning from "throwing up."

Comment: Is there any other word for 'rolling eyes'? I mean for the same kind of expression or feeling.

Answer (score 4):

*Roll eyes* means *turn (one's eyes) upward, typically to show surprise or disapproval*.

> Sarah rolled her eyes.

Comment: More than that, to me it's "**being annoyed** with something unworthy/plainly dumb/obvious" or expressing something like "Told ya!"

Comment: (stupid parser is stupid)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this phrase used in the context of technical documentation. The phrase is often used specifically in the context of *teenagers* rolling their eyes at something their parents, or another authority figure, is saying. Given this context I believe the sense of "rolling your eyes" includes a connotation of silent resistance, or only grudging acceptance, of that authority figure's pronouncement. The resistance could be to excessive repetition, or it could be resistance more generally to the right of the speaker to make the statement or issue the instruction that is met with rolling eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do "roll your eyes" upward to express disbelief.

To the heavens, specifically, as in "Saints preserve us, is this guy for real?!"

Comment: +! *Disbelief* is usually closest to the true meaning.

Comment: Specifically, not amazed disbelief or doubtful disbelief, but annoyed, bored, dissenting disbelief.